# Neutron star near black hole mass in a moving frame

Tags: energy, black-holes, elementary-particles, neutron-stars

Consider a neutron star with a mass close to that necessary to form a black hole. In a moving frame, it has additional kinetic energy, and its energy density should increase.

Why is it not possible that in a sufficiently fast-moving frame, it would exceed the threshold to form a black hole? For that matter, why can a similar argument not be used for elementary particles?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it not possible that in a sufficiently fast-moving frame, it would exceed the threshold to form a black hole?

In general relativity (GR), the theory that predicts the existence of black holes, the source of gravity is not just the energy density. It is the entire [stress energy tensor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor).

The energy density is the time-time component of this tensor, and has the usual attractive gravitational effects. However, momentum density is the time-space component of the stress energy tensor, and (although it is more complicated than this simple statement) it can be thought of as having a gravitational effect that cancels out some of the effect of the time-time component.

So, as you look at different frames you will see both an increased time-time component and an increased time-space component. The second largely cancels out the effect of the first. So a fast moving neutron star does not become a black hole.

Furthermore, the usual black hole solution assumes spherical symmetry. A fast moving star is no longer spherically symmetric, so that solution does not apply.